# A structure in which every element is a lynchpin

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase for a structure in which every element is a lynchpin? To clarify: the removal of any part of this structure would cause it to collapse entirely.

> The system is a/an X; removal of any part of it causes the rest to collapse.

Comment: A descriptive phrase is 'stripped to its bare essentials'.

Comment: Every element is a _keystone_.

Comment: You could think of the sentence as being in an *unstable equilibrium.*

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the term *irreducibly complex*. Unfortunately, this is a term of art in the pseudoscience of so-called "intelligent design", which purports to challenge the Darwinian concept of evolution through natural selection. Here's a definition from one of the psuedoscientists, Michael Behe:

> A single system which is composed of several interacting parts that contribute to the basic function, and where **the removal of any one of the parts causes the system to effectively cease functioning**.

(Emphasis mine. This is from Behe's book *Darwin's Black Box* as quoted on Wikipedia.)

Comment: This is such a loaded term that I'd personally never use it unironically. I've only ever heard it employed by people attempting to disprove evolution. That said, it does fit the bill for the OPs request and is a good answer as far as that's concerned. So... upvoted. :)

Comment: @ParthianShot Indeed.The term's creationist baggage may render it useless. Ironic, as the concept was recognized by biologists decades before the pseudoscientists got hold of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that ***[house of cards](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/house-of-cards)*** is a good metaphor for what you are looking for:

> - a structure or plan that is insubstantial and subject to imminent collapse, as a structure made by balancing playing cards against each other.

(Dictionary.com)

- The system is a house of cards; removal of any part of it causes the rest to collapse.

Comment: This is a good start, and I have upvoted the comment. Ideally though, I'd like a phrase which conjures up more of an image that every component relies on every other, rather than one of particular fragility.

Comment: OP does not require the 'insubstantial' element which this demands.

Comment: And right as I was considering referencing the game Jenga... good to know!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - insubstantial refers to the inherent fragility typical of a structure which  collapses  just by removing one element .

Comment: 'Insubstantial and subject to imminent collapse' is woefully inaccurate when referring to a structure where each element is extremely strong as well as vital. Most anchor chains had very long lifespans.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - insubstantial: 
*not solid or firm; weak  flimsy*. How can such a structure be solid and strong if it collapses just by removing one element? It is fragile by definition.

Comment: Doubtless the Tyne Bridge would collapse if one hinge failed.

Comment: `How can such a structure be solid and strong if it collapses just by removing one element? It is fragile by definition.` No, it is not, if removing one element would be extremely difficult. Fragile means *easy to break*. By your definition, anything is fragile. A nuclear submarine would be broken without its hull, but it would be ridiculous to argue that that makes it fragile.

Comment: @ParthianShot - I think you are just missing the point here. Are you familiar with figurative language?

Comment: Yep. And the figure of speech "house of cards" is used to imply that something, rather than being free of cruft, bells, and whistles, is simply shoddy. Substandard. Liable to collapse at the slightest provocation, with the smallest puff of wind. It certainly does not imply that the thing is efficient in its construction (i.e. has only the parts necessary).

Answer (score 0):

[Barebones](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barebones) would probably be best, here.

[Minimum working example / minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) is also an option.

The wikipedia article says the term is limited to software, but that's inaccurate (source: I'm a native speaker. It is, at a bare minimum, used in other engineering disciplines).

However, calling something a MWE would imply that the thing is an *example*, and not necessarily a market-ready or production-ready product. It implies that the thing has only the core components needed to function, but may not be ideally suited to the ultimate task in mind. The phrase is often used interchangeably with the phrase "[proof of concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept)", although the two are not precisely synonymous.

Comment: Really? A downvote?
With no explanation?
"Bare bones" is perfect. Its definition encompasses exactly what the OP is looking for.